# Question about getting probability from a CDF

Tags: probability, statistics

Just wondering but if I had the following CDF:

$$ F_X(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
\frac{x+2}{8} & 0 \leq x < 6 \\
1 & x \geq 6 \\
\end{cases} $$
If I wanted to calculate the probability $P(X=6)$ and $P(7\leq X \leq 8)$ How would I go about this ? In my textbook and in my class we have only ever talked/did examples where the probability were within the interval, say for this example,  $[0,5]$ so I am just curious on how I would do this type of question here. Thank you

Comment: You should write $P(X=6),$ not $P(x=6).$ Notice that you wrote $f_X(x),$ with one capital $X$ and one lower-case $x.$ There is a reason why one is capital and the other is in lower case. Without that we wouldn't understand things like $P(X\le x).$ Also, not that usually a capital $F$ is use for a c.d.f. and a lower-case $f$ for a density or a mass function. $\qquad$

Comment: . . . and now I've done some corrections by editing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general if $F$ is the CDF of a random variable $X$ then
$$
F(x)=P(X\leq x).
$$
If $\{y_n\}$ is a sequence such that $y_n\uparrow x$ (for example take $y_n=x-1/n$, then $\{X\leq y_n\}\uparrow \{X< x\}$. Thus
$$
P(X<x)=\lim_{y\,\uparrow x} F(y)=F(x^{-})
$$
and so
$$
P(X=x)=P(X\leq x)-P(X<x)=F(x)-F(x^{-}).
$$
In your case
$$
P(X=6)=F(6)-\frac{6+2}{8}=1-1=0
$$
and
$$
P(7\leq X\leq 8)=P(X\leq 8)-P(X<7)=F(8)-F(7^{-})=1-1=0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the cdf is greater than $0$ for $X >0$ and less than $1$ for $X < 6$. Therefore, the support of $X$ is $[0,6]$; this is where $X$ can take values, and (speaking informally) $f_X(x)$  tells how much probability mass is associated with each value in $ x \in [0,6]$.

Since $X$ is a continuous random variable, $P(X=6)=0$.

Since $X$ does not take on values in the interval $[7,8$], $P( 7 \le X \le 8)=0$.